# example to show a nonnegative finite-valued Borel measurable function is not $\sigma$-finite

Tags: real-analysis

Give a counterexample to show that the following statement is false.

If  $\mu$ is a measure (on a $\sigma$-field $F$ of subsets of $\Omega$) and $f:\Omega \to R$ is a nonnegative finite-valued Borel measurable function, then the measure $\lambda$ defined by

$\lambda (A)=\int_{A}f d\mu$

is $\sigma$-finite.

Definition of $\sigma$-finite: A non-negative finitely additive set function $\mu$ on a field $F$ is said to be $\sigma$-finite on $F$ iff $\Omega$  can be written as $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_{n}$ where $A_{n}$ belong to $F$  and $\mu(A_{n})<\infty$ for all $n$.

Answer (score 0):

Take $\Omega=\mathbb{R}$, $\mathscr{F}=\{A:A\subset\mathbb{R}\}$ and $\mu$ is the counting measure. $f:=1$. Then
$$\lambda(A)=card(A).$$
It is obvious that $\lambda$ is not $\sigma-$finite.